# invalid new-expression of abstract class type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, abstract-class

I am currently writing a raytracer for a university class.
In order to load Scenes from files I wrote an sdfloader to read sdf files and create scenes therefor.

if I now want to compile the loader i get the following error:

```
rc/sdf_loader.cpp: In member function 'void SDFloader::add_shape(std::istringstream&)':
src/sdf_loader.cpp:95:58: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'box'
                                &scene_.materials[mat]));
                                                      ^
```

I tried to find a solution but failed.

The sdf_loader class looks like the following:

```
class SDFloader {
  public:
    SDFloader();
    ~SDFloader();

    Scene const& scene() const;
    void read(std::string file);

  private:
    void add_material(std::istringstream&);
    void add_shape(std::istringstream&);
    void add_light(std::istringstream&);
    void add_camera(std::istringstream&);
    void apply_transformation(std::istringstream&);

  private:
    Scene scene_;
};
```

in my implementation of the sdf loader i wrote the method read():

```
void SDFloader::add_shape(std::istringstream& iss) {

    std::string name;
    iss >> name;

    if(name == "box") {
      double x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2;
      std::string mat;
      iss >> name >> x1 >> y1 >> z1 >> x2 >> y2 >> z2 >> mat;
      scene_.shapes.insert(new box(point(x1,y1,z1),
                                   point(x2,y2,z2),
                                   name,
                                   &scene_.materials[mat]));
    }
```

and for every other shape the same calls.

Where is the Problem in my code? I really don't see it

I am using `g++-4.9 - std=c++0x` to compile and link everything

Comment: Perhaps `box` class has a pure virtual method?

Comment: Apparently, `box` is abstract, i.e. it has pure virtual functions. You can't create instances of abstract classes.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

> invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'box'

There is nothing unclear about the error message. Your class `box` has at least one member that is not implemented, which means it is abstract. You cannot instantiate an abstract class.

If this is a bug, fix your box class by implementing the missing member(s).

If it's by design, derive from box, implement the missing member(s) and use the derived class.

Comment: i have all the methods of my class defined and implemented  ,  but stil getting the same error , any help

Comment: @BhawinParkeria Look harder. You have missed one.

Comment: Your class may derive from another class that has pure virtual functions (those that defined with =0 ) you should implement them in your class.

Answer (score 26):

for others scratching their heads, I came across this error because I had innapropriately const-qualified one of the arguments to a method in a base class, so the derived class member functions were not over-riding it. so make sure you don't have something like

```
class Base 
{
  public:
      virtual void foo(int a, const int b) = 0;
}
class D: public Base 
{
 public:
     void foo(int a, int b){};
}
```

Comment: That's why you should use the ```override``` keyword.

Answer (score 15):

If you use C++11, you can use the specifier "override", and it will give you a compiler error if your aren't correctly overriding an abstract method.  You probably have a method that doesn't match exactly with an abstract method in the base class, so your aren't actually overriding it.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override

Answer (score 5):

#### Another possible cause for future Googlers

I had this issue because a method I was trying to implement required a `std::unique_ptr<Queue>(myQueue)` as a parameter, but the `Queue` class is abstract. I solved that by using a `QueuePtr(myQueue)` constructor like so:

```
using QueuePtr = std::unique_ptr<Queue>;
```

and used that in the parameter list instead. This fixes it because the initializer tries to create a copy of `Queue` when you make a `std::unique_ptr` of its type, which can't happen.